# Old clang++ not compiling after installing LLVM-12?

Tags: c++, clang++

I am working on a C++ project using zapcc which is based on LLVM-7, in Ubuntu 16.04 wsl2.

It builds the project fine for a year.

Today I intalled LLVM-12 to test lldb and after an hour the project suddenly won't compile, with the error:

`/usr/include/c++/9/memory:177:16: fatal error: no member named 'is_constant_evaluated' in namespace 'std'`

my current compiler flag:

`-std=gnu++2a  -stdlib=libstdc++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wno-ignored-attributes -Werror=return-type -Wfatal-errors`

I checked that I only have `5` `5.5.0`  `9` in `/usr/include/c++/`

How can I fix this?

(Just after I install LLVM-12, I could still compile the project, for many times, but after an hour it suddenly failed.)

(I cannot drop the `gnu++2a` flag since the project depends on it)

(I can build the project fine with clang++12, but zapcc builds much faster.)

Comment: Just guessing but you might want to try `-std=c++20` rather than `-std=gnu++2a` .

Comment: @G.M.  not works =(

Comment: Try to install a more recent gcc/libstdc++ (from wherever you got that gcc-9)? C++20 support is experimental anyway.

Comment: Now I just comment out a few lines in the std header, and it works again...

Comment: @MarcGlisse I reinstalled g++-9 but sadly it didn't reinstall the headers

Comment: but why specifically 9, why not try a different version?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I would try later, at least it can build now